# Javascript help, Trying to animate two different sprites at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, sprite

I need some javascript help. I am trying to set up two sprite animations with different frame rates in two separate div.

Here is a fiddle I started and i am very much stuck.

How do I combine the two div IDs into one statement? OR Should I be using ClassName in the statement to run on both divs?

http://jsfiddle.net/akwilinski/3t7d6qbL/1/

```
<div id="animate" class="animation"></div>
<div id="animate2" class="animation2"></div>

onload = function startAnimation() { 
    var frameHeight = 400; 
    var frames = 27; 
    var frame = 0; 
    var div = document.getElementById("animate"); 
    setInterval(function () { 
        var frameOffset = (++frame % frames) * -frameHeight; 
        div.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + frameOffset + "px"; 
    }, 100); 

}
```

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: What is the question? What specific part are you having trouble with? Try to write it in such a way that the question is written out, so the answer can be clear and to the point as well =) P.S. The jsfiddle isn't running for me.

Comment: Thanks @Mwr247 i edited this post and fixed the jfiddle link.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dy4hn83x/1/ Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AnthonyTJRivas I think it may involve different frame rates, per the question. To AnnK: What is the frame rate you're looking to run the second one at?

Comment: @Mwr247 I actually noticed that after i posted. Already have an updated fiddle for it edited into the comment!

Comment: @AnthonyTJRivas yes that is what I am trying to achieve. But the second div has 30 frames.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! @AnthonyTJRivas I'm going to use your method as it used what I started with with out starting fresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to do this using the method you have already started using is to define 2 new variables, 1 for the second div and one for the second frame count. Then you can just add the call to your function.

Updated js:

```
onload = function startAnimation() { 
var frameHeight = 400; 
var frames = 27; 
var frame = 0; 
var div = document.getElementById("animate"); 
var div2 = document.getElementById("animate2");
setInterval(function () { 
    var frameOffset = (++frame % frames) * -frameHeight; 
    var frameOffset2 = (++frame % frames) * -frameHeight - 10; 
    div.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + frameOffset + "px"; 
    div2.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + frameOffset + "px"; 
}, 100);

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dy4hn83x/4/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/f4v1vy7x/5/

I made a Can object to store the configuration for each can (so you can have different frameHeights, frames and frameRates.

I used window.requestAnimationFrame because it's far more efficient than setInterval. On each available frame I check whether it's time to animate based on each Can's set frame rate:

```
var Can = function( selector, frameHeight, frames, frameRate )
{
    this.domCan = document.getElementById( selector );
    this.frameHeight = frameHeight;
    this.frames = frames;
    this.frameRate = frameRate;
    this.frame = 0;
};

onload = function startAnimation() { 
    var can1 = new Can( 'animate', 400, 27, 20 );
    var can2 = new Can( 'animate2', 400, 27, 100 );

    var cans = [ can1, can2 ]; 

    window.requestAnimationFrame( function() {
        can1.start = can2.start = new Date();
        animate( cans );
    } );
};

var animate = function( cans ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < cans.length; i++ ) {       
        var now = new Date();
        var can = cans[i];
        if( now - can.start >= 1000 / can.frameRate ) {
            can.start = now;
            var frameOffset = (++can.frame % can.frames) * -can.frameHeight; 
            can.domCan.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + frameOffset + "px";
        }
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame( function() {
        animate( cans );
    } );
}
```

Comment: I like your method as well. Thank you for sharing and showing me a different way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var div = document.getElementById("animate"); 
var div2 = document.getElementById("animate2");

function anim(div) {
    setInterval(function () { 
        var frameOffset = (++frame % frames) * -frameHeight; 
        div.style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + frameOffset + "px"; 
    }, 100); 
}

anim(div);
anim(div2);
```

You could then pass in additional parameters like frameHeight, frame, and frames to further customize each animation.

Comment: Thank you for replying  I ended up used @AnthonyTJRivas method above.